# AG-Grid: How can I hide disable the "Reset Columns" option in the menu option?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How can I hide disable the "Reset Columns" option in the menu option in ag-grid? I am using the default menu options, but I want to hide or disable the "Reset Columns" option. I could use CSS/JS to override this, but I am looking for a way to rather disable this from Ag-grid directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to do it:

```
  getMainMenuItems(params) {
    params.defaultItems.pop() // removes "resetColumns"
    params.defaultItems.pop() // removes "separator"
    params.defaultItems.pop() // removes "separator"

    return params.defaultItems
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TypeScript, this approach lets you specify which items to remove rather than relying on the order of the items:

```js
public getMainMenuItems(params: GetMainMenuItemsParams): (string | MenuItemDef)[] {

    const itemsToRemove = [
        "autoSizeThis",
        "autoSizeAll",
        "separator",
        "resetColumns"
    ];

    params.defaultItems = params.defaultItems.filter(item => !itemsToRemove.includes(item));

    return params.defaultItems
}
```